# How to cache the result in console application c# .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, caching, console-application

I have console application where I am reading a data from json file store on local disk drive. I want to cache that result when app run first time in console and display result when user wants it.  I do not want to read it again and again from disk. In web based I know how to do caching but I am stuck because its console app and not sure how to do. Application design wise, I am using repository pattern and  .net 6

Comment: You put it in a variable. That's it. It's easier in a desktop app than a web app.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I want to store that when app running for the first time and then display it when user demands it.

Comment: So what's the problem? Assign it to a variable and then get it from that variable when you need it. I'm not seeing an issue here. I think that you're over-complicating this. Like I said, it's easier in a desktop app than a web app. The user always has access to the whole thing in a desktop app, where they are only connected to the server intermittently with a web app. You have to persists data between those connections and that's the complication but that doesn't exist in a desktop app.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks a  lot for this hint. I have implemented in constructor of class when app loading in console for first time. Thanks again.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think @jmcilhinney means an ENVIRONMENT variable, not just a variable in the console app, since after running a command, the app will stop

Comment: @LLL, I don't because I'm working under the assumption that we're talking about while the app is running. Just because it's a console app doesn't mean that it will be exiting immediately.

Comment: @jmcilhinney fair point

Answer (score 0):

If your console application is not complex. You can simply store the results and reuse anytime with a variable which references your object(s).

In case you want something more appropriate, you can use the built in memory cache implementation.

You would need to register the service (assuming you are making use of DI):

```
services.AddMemoryCache()
```

Then you can inject the memory cache instance and use it as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0).